# get_the_tags function not retrieve all tags for specific category

Tags: tags

I use this code below to retrieve all tags from a specific category. The code is working correctly, but only returns three tags in stead of all tags (I assigned six tags for this category). These three tags I assigned at (07/6/2016) but other three tags assigned at (01/1/2016). Does the problem return to archive?

```
query_posts('category_name=technology');
if (have_posts()) { 
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        $custom_cattags = get_the_tags();
        if ($custom_cattags) {
           foreach($custom_cattags as $custom_cattag) {
              $tags_array[] = $custom_cattag->slug;
           }
       }
    }
}
$tags_arrs = array_unique($tags_array);
echo print_r($tags_array);
```

Comment: Why don't you use [`get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) for this?

Comment: @cjbj I don't know how use get_terms function for retrieve all tags in specific category if you know help me

Comment: Just to get things straight. You have a category called "technology". The posts in that category also have tags. And now you want a list of all the tags that are attached to all the posts in the technology category. Right?

Comment: @cjbj yes, I want that you say

Comment: what is your number under 'settings - reading - blog page show at most [] posts'? try to add a 'posts_per_page' parameter with -1 to your query.

Comment: @Michael thanks i add `post_per_page=-1` now show all six tags. but how I can add condition until only show me five tags instead of six tabs